# Compare Survey Results Across Regions

Tags: r

I have results from a survey of nurse practitioners asking to what degree (Likert scale, values from 1-5) they feel certain barriers prevent them from adequate practice (i.e. time constraint, location restrictions, etc.). They were also asked to locate where in the state they practice (fill in a bubble). I was wondering if there was a way to code a picture of a U.S. state (say Texas) and superimpose the survey results onto the map by region? 
For example: Say one nurse indicated a 1 for feeling time constrained, and she was from the Southern region of Texas. Then, I wold like to show that, out of say a sample of 100, that 1% who responded with a value of 1 came from the Southern region, and have that appear on a map of Texas. Does that make sense?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, what you describe is possible, but your question is currently not really an R question. It would be easier for us to help you if you provide some sample data and what you've tried so far. Right now the question is too broad to usefully answer.

Comment: Yeah, what you describe sounds possible, but try a tutorial e.g https://www.computerworld.com/article/3038270/create-maps-in-r-in-10-fairly-easy-steps.html and if you hit a problem then come back with your problem (and the error) and we will do our best to help.